# Socket io 'on' callback running multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have a react app that uses socket io to send for and receive all data. I created a global socket variable to be shared across all components...

```
export let gameScoket = null
export const update = (newSocket) => gameScoket = newSocket
```

I then set the socket in 'Home.jsx' and make a few calls...

```
update(io("ws://localhost:8888"))
socket = gameScoket

socket.on('...')
```

The problem arose when adding a callbacks to these calls. The callbacks seems to be called a random (very large) amount of times, increasing every time the socket is used. An example of this can be seen in these three sockets in 'Game.jsx'...

```
socket.on("question-update", (data) => {
    console.log("Calling question-update")
    const responce = JSON.parse(data)
    setQuizData(responce.data)
})
socket.on("point-update", (data) => {
    console.log("Calling point-update")
    const responce = JSON.parse(data)
    setUsrData(responce.data)
})
socket.on("personal-point-update", (data) => {
    console.log("Calling personal-point-update")
    const responce = JSON.parse(data)
    setClientScore(responce.data)
})
```

Whilst there is no evidence of the client spamming the server with requests, the console is bombed with messages, and the state is re-updated so many times the app becomes unresponsive and crashes. Here's a screenshot of the console...
[image: Browser console with many messages]

I don't know where I went wrong with my implementation and would love some advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to keep all 'socket.on()' call within useEffect to prevent duplication.

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on('...')
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use socket.once("",(data)=>{});

The bug in your code is that each time a new connection() is called node registers an event listener 'Quest'. So first time new connection() is called the number of event listeners with event 'Quest' is one, the second time function is called, the number of event listeners increases to two, and so on

socket. once() ensures that the number of event listeners bound to a socket with event 'Quest' registered is exactly one

Comment: Hi, I've tried updating all my socket.on listeners to socket.once listeners but still receive the same results, strange. Nonetheless, thank you for your suggestion.